# Как получить тип произвольной NFC-метки в режиме её чтения?

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc

Пытаюсь создать приложение для смартфонов, которое будет копировать NFC-метки.
Столкнулся с проблемой невозможности в некоторых случаях получить у метки её тип.

Имеется метод

```
/**
 * Callback when a new tag is discovered by the system.
 * <p>
 * <p>Communication with the card should take place here.
 *
 * @param tag Discovered tag
 */
@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    MifareClassic mifareClassic = MifareClassic.get(tag);

    if (mifareClassic != null) {
        mAccountCallback.get().onTagsTypeReceived(
            TECH_TYPE_MFR_CLASS, mifareClassic.getType());
        mAccountCallback.get().onMifareClassicReceived(mifareClassic);
    }
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);

    if (nfcA != null) {
        mAccountCallback.get().onNfcAReceived(nfcA);
    }
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
}
```

Для тега, который содержит в списке технологий MifareClassic или MifareUltralight доступ к типу метки есть через

```
.getType()
```

Но если этих технологий нет, то данный метод становится недоступным.
Однако при чтении тех же самых меток при помощи подключенного к ПК ридера b программки Arduino 1.8.5 их данные считываются без проблем:

[image: Скриншот монитора вывода из Arduino 1.8.5]

Вопрос: что сделать, чтобы можно было получить тип любой метки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для произвольной NFC метки задачу пока решить не удалось. Найдено решение только для NFC-меток типа А. Документ компании ["NXP Semiconductors" AN10833 "MIFARE Type Identification Procedure"](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10833.pdf) в п. 3.2 Coding of Select Acknowledge (SAK) определяет соответствие значений SAK различным типам тэгов. На его основании получился такой код:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        String type = "";
        int mSak = (int) (sak & 0x7F);

        if (mTagType.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.tag_type))) {
            switch (mSak) {
                case 0x04:
                    type = getString(R.string.sak_indicates_uid_is_not_complete);
                    break;
                case 0x09:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_classic_protocol_320_bytes);
                    break;
                case 0x08:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_classic_protocol_1kb);
                    break;
                case 0x18:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_classic_protocol_4kb);
                    break;
                case 0x00:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_ultralight_or_ultralight_c);
                    break;
                case 0x10:
                case 0x11:
                    type = getString(R.string.mifare_plus);
                    break;
                case 0x01:
                    type = getString(R.string.only_mentioned_in_nxp_an_10833_mifare_type_identification_procedure);
                    break;
                case 0x20:
                    type = getString(R.string.picc_compliant_with_iso_iec_14443_4);
                    break;
                case 0x40:
                    type = getString(R.string.picc_compliant_with_iso_iec_18092_nfc);
                    break;
                default:
                    type = getString(R.string.picc_type_unknown);
                    break;
                }
                mTagType.setText(type);
            }

        }
    });
```

Для получения значения SAK служит метод класса android.nfc.tech.NfcA:

```
.getSak()
```